# animation runs when scroll to the top in amp-html

Tags: html, amp-html

I use this code to do some animation effect in an amp-html page

```
<amp-position-observer 
   on="enter:expandAnim.start; 
   exit:shrinkAnim.start;" 
   layout="nodisplay"> 
</amp-position-observer>
```

this code run when I scrolling down form top of the page.
and in exit mode, when I scrolling up to the top, It runs only when I reach the top of the page. but I want each time I scrolling up, it runs.(not when I reach the top of the page ).

something like this:

```
exit:scroll_up: shrinkAnim.start;"
```

Is it possible in `amp-position-observer` component?